# Want to run docker in windows server 2016 on azure

Tags: azure, docker, cloud, windows-server-2016

I want to run docker on windows server 2016 in Azure but, i am only able to find windows server 2016 data center which is very costly? is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a special edition of Windows Server 2016 on Azure called `Windows Server 2016 Datacenter - with Containers` which costs exactly the same as 2012 R2. Azure doesn't allow for nested virtualization, so prices for Windows VM's without extra software are equal.

Comment: i tried to use it but options available for  Windows Server 2016 Datacenter - with Containers are very costly, is there any alternate solution for it on azure?

Comment: you can choose HDD instead of SSD, which would cut cost a lot (you would be able to select A1 or A2 for your server). Or you could switch to linux with HDD, that would be even cheaper